# Composite Binomial (Poisson) probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 10 Bernoulli sensors, each has the probability of 1E-4 of “success”; sensors are independent. I run 10,000 trials for each of the 10 sensors. What is the probability of observing at least 3 “successes” in more than 2 sensors?

R (or Python or Mathematica) code would be best. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of successes observed from one sensor.

Then $X \tilde {  } B(10000, 0.0001)$

Let $p=P($at least $3$ successes$)=1 -\left\{P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)\right\}$

where $P(X=r)=_{10000}C_r \times 0.0001^r \times 0.9999^{10000-r}$

The complications involved in calculating this means that we can take advantage of the fact that a Poisson distribution is a good approximation to a Binomial distribution in situations where the probability of success is small (which is certainly the case with $P($success$)=0.0001$.

So $X \approx X'$, where $X' \tilde { } Poisson (1)$

$p=1 -\left\{P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)\right\}$

where $P(X=r)=\frac{e^{-1}1^r}{r!}$

Let $Y$ be the number of sensors where at least 3 successes are observed.

Then $Y \tilde {  } B(10, p)$

You want $Y$ to be more than 2.

This is $P(Y > 2)=1 -\left\{P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)\right\}$

where $P(Y=r)=_{10}C_r \times p^r \times (1-p)^{10-r}$

In this case no approximation is required.